# Why do these two programs give different outputs in VC++2008?

Tags: c, strcmp, strncmp

Why do these two programs give different outputs in VC++2008?

After all, the same strings are compared.

### strcmp__usage.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() 
{
char targetString[] = "klmnop";

printf ("Compare = %d\n", strcmp(targetString, "abcdef"));
printf ("Compare = %d\n", strcmp(targetString, "abcdefgh"));
printf ("Compare = %d\n", strcmp(targetString, "jlmnop"));
printf ("Compare = %d\n", strcmp(targetString, "klmnop"));
printf ("Compare = %d\n", strcmp(targetString, "klmnoq"));
printf ("Compare = %d\n", strcmp(targetString, "uvwxyz"));
printf ("Compare = %d\n", strcmp(targetString, "xyz"));
}
```

### Output

```
Compare = 1
Compare = 1
Compare = 1
Compare = 0
Compare = -1
Compare = -1
Compare = -1
```

### strncmp_usage.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() 
{   
    char targetString[] = "klmnopqrstuvwxyz";   
    int n = 6;

    printf ("Compare = %d\n", strncmp(targetString, "abcdef", n));
    printf ("Compare = %d\n", strncmp(targetString, "abcdefgh", n));
    printf ("Compare = %d\n", strncmp(targetString, "jlmnop", n));
    printf ("Compare = %d\n", strncmp(targetString, "klmnop", n));
    printf ("Compare = %d\n", strncmp(targetString, "klmnoq", n));
    printf ("Compare = %d\n", strncmp(targetString, "uvwxyz", n));
    printf ("Compare = %d\n", strncmp(targetString, "xyz", n));
}
```

### Output

```
Compare = 10
Compare = 10
Compare = 1
Compare = 0
Compare = -1
Compare = -10
Compare = -13
```

Comment: maybe give us the output so we don't have to guess?

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eywx8zcx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Also http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/strcmp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strcmp.html) and [strncmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strncmp.html) provide the guarantee that the result will include:

> A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
>   A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

The actual number returned (1/-1 or 12/-13) is implementation specific, and can be any value.  The only portion that matters is that both return 0, less than zero, or greater than zero.  In that respect, they provide the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

From strncmp:

Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
A zero value indicates that the characters compared in both strings are all equal.
A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Clearly strcmp always returns 1 or -1 for nonequal characters, while strncmp returns the difference between the nonequal characters. Since that behaviour is undefined it isn't a problem.